# Back button in JSP

Tags: jsp

Hi guys i'm new and this is my first question i really hope you can help.

i have three JSP pages and the middle one contains a back button

the first page has a list of items generated from a database and also contains pagination.

the last page has some details in it and a back button.

My problem is that on the middle page if i click on the back button it begins back at the beginning of the pagination, i need it to go to the previous place in the pagination.

I have tried history-1 function this works but if i go to page 3 and then go back to page 2 and then use the back button it takes me back to page 3.

It is a bit confusing, but i hope someone can help.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question and I'm new to these boards.
Here is my current suggestion.

```
<script>document.write("<a href=\"" + document.referrer + "\">Back</a>");</script>
```

Not only will this go to the previous page, but it also shows what the previous pages address is.

This has an advantage over the other way to do this in javascript:

```
javascript:history.go(-1);
```

This is because the go method of the history object will not display the previous pages address.

Will this work for you?

Comment: Thank you, i'll definitely give this a try update as soon as i can.